# io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.logstream.LogController why was this removed in 3.3.0 quarkus

Tags: logging, jboss, quarkus

as  it was previously present in 3.2.10 version quarkus to change log levels in runtime and where any alternatives for this

debug level of the jboss loggers can be changed using LogContext but for actual logging to take effect i am being forced to set my root log level as well which i dont want to

Answer (score 1):

This was removed with the removal of the old Dev UI. The new Dev UI allow you to do this from the UI when running in Dev mode. Alternatively you can look at the quarkiverse logging manager (https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-logging-manager). This can also work for non Dev modes